# Assign variables into a dictionary object in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class in Flutter as follows:

```
class Customer {
  final String name;
  final String phone;

  const Customer({
    required this.name,
    required this.phone,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'phone': phone,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Customer{name: $name, phone: $phone}';
  }
}
```

In another class, where I have two initial values for name and phone.
I tried to assign the two values to an dictionary object customer:

```
class CustomerForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomerForm({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomerForm> createState() => _CustomerFormState();
}
class _CustomerFormState extends State<CustomerForm> {
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String name = 'Dan';
  String phone = '1234';

  var customer = const Customer(   
    name: name,
    phone: phone,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Add Customers'),
        ),
        body: Form(
          key: _formkey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Name of Customer or Employer',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      name = value;
                    });
                  },
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter the name of your customer or your employer';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Phone of Customer or Employer',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      phone = value;
                    });
                  },
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter the phone of your customer or your employer';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
                        );
                      }
                      print({'name': name, 'phone': phone});                      
                    },
                    child: const Text('Submit'),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

However, there are errors while it is ok to put the two values directly into the object.

> A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'String' in a const constructor.
> Try using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'

if I removed the 'const', I have another error:

> The instance member 'name' can't be accessed in an initializer.
> Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression.

Your suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: It would help, if you could show more of your code.

Comment: Please share the code wherer you are creating the customer object

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a variable to an initializer.

```
String a = "a";
String b = const a; Or String b = a;
```

to fix this:

```
static String a = "a";
String b = a;
```

or as you are assigning these values later by text field controllers, then better create a method to assign these values:

```
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();

  Customer customer = const Customer(name: "", phone: "");

  void addCustomer() {
    setState(() {
      customer = Customer(name: nameController.text, phone: phoneController.text);
    });
  }
```